# How to change the number pattern in gsp?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have one domain class which has one numeric field. Default scaffolding generated it. When I enter a number with more than 3 digits, ex:- 1234, then in show.gsp and list.gsp it shows as 1,234. My requirement is to show the number without comma. I can't use g:formatNumber because I have more than 50 domains and not able to use this tag for every gsp page. Is there anything I can do to change the number pattern globally?

thanks

Comment: Could you post your code (the part where you describe your field) of show.gsp?

Comment: <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name"><g:message code="formulationType.id.label" default="Id" /></td>
                            
                            <td valign="top" class="value">${fieldValue(bean: formulationTypeInstance, field: "id")}</td>
                            
                        </tr>  this is the part of show.gsp

Answer (score 0):

maybe solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440299/584392) can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Get the field directly like:

```
<td valign="top" class="value">${formulationTypeInstance?.id}</td>
```

Of course you may lose some of the tag's features with it, like highlighting field when a validation error occurs. But you're in show.gsp and it shouldn't have text fields or something to submit, so you lose nothing! Simple is the way to go here. =)