# Prevent Grails fieldValue from formatting numbers

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 3.3.9 with [Fields plugin](https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields) . This plugin calls the fieldValue tag on numbers at line 862 here. [FormFieldsTagLib.groovy](https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/8b1064d3fb1bb9b5726f9c8a3cc8e8203874c6ff/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/formfields/FormFieldsTagLib.groovy#L862) . And for some reason this fieldValue tag is formatting numbers with a comma, even when the default format for the en_US locale is '0', which shoudln't be adding a comma. Is there a config to stop Grails from adding a comma when the fieldValue tag is invoked? Right now if the bean has an Integer property with a value of 2019, it gets rendered as 2,019.

To recreate, you can just do `grails create-app myapp` and then create a domain class with an integer property. Enable scaffolding, save a record and fetch it back. You will see it has comma in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason behind the commas by debugging through the code in ValidationTaglib.groovy . It is invoking asText method on a PropertyEditor as shown here: [ValidationTagLib](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/02f20e41d9bfe6ce26bfe61259428e22c169db7d/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ValidationTagLib.groovy#L470) . Grails registers property editors [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web-common/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/beans/PropertyEditorRegistryUtils.groovy). So to fix it, you'll have to define your own Editor for Integer. You'll have to define your own PropertyEditorRegistrar to register the custom Editor, then declare it as a Spring bean as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12197559/1036405).